# PostgreSQL: How to get Date only for using Now()?

Tags: postgresql-9.1

I am using the following query

```
SELECT NOW() - TO_DATE('2015-12-07 13:37:34.055951+08','YYYYMMDD') AS "AgingDate"
```

which gives this result:

```
414 days 13:40:20.513244
```

How can I remove the timestamp portion of the output?  I only want the number of days.

Please help me..

thanks!

Comment: Please review the answers given below, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SELECT EXTRACT(epoch FROM calculation)`, where `calculation` is the difference you had in the original problem.  `EXTRACT(epoch FROM ...)` will return the number of seconds since the epoch.  This can be converted to days by dividing by `60*60*24`.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(epoch FROM (now() - to_date('2015-12-07 13:37:34.055951+08','YYYYMMDD'))) /
    (60*60*24) AS "AgingDate"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select now()::date - to_date('2015-12-07 13:37:34.055951+08','YYYYMMDD');
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/5096)**